# how to pass selected option id value to codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i want to pass selected option value in id to codeigniter controller.

```
<p>
        <select id="quantity" name="quantity" tabindex="2" onchange="calculate(this)" required autofocus>
            <option value="">Choose Your Quantity</option>
            <?php
                if($prodqty)
                {
                    foreach($prodqty as $qty)
                    {
                        for($i = $qty->quantity_from; $i <= $qty->quantity_to; $i++)
                        {   
            ?>
            <option value="<?=$i?>" id="<?=$qty->discount?>"><?=$i?></option>
            <?php } } } ?>
        </select>
      </p>
```

i am already getter selected option value, now i want to get id value also i.e. id="discount?>"

```
function add_cart_prod()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
```

this is controller where i want to get id value

Comment: what are you getting in $prodqty

Answer (score 0):

If you subitted the data via POST, which I suppose, because you test the POST-Array, you should get them this way:

```
$this->input->get_post('quantity');
```

But perhaps you used in your HTML the option GET for the form submission, then this should work:

```
$this->input->get('quantity');
```

If you want to get both values XSS-clean you should add a second paramenter, which is set to TRUE:

```
$this->input->get_post('quantity',TRUE);
```

As discussed below you should change the value of the option to:

```
<option value="<?=$i?>_<?=$qty->discount?>"><?=$i?></option>
```

And then explode the array by this char: "_" to get the two values:

```
$valuearray = explode ( "_" , $this->input->get_post('quantity'));
```

$valuearray[0] should contain your $i-part and $valuearray[1] the discount.

Important is, that the delimiter-char cannot be a value of either $i or $qty->discount. Otherwise choose a different char

Comment: how will he get the id of the selected option?

Comment: The id is quantity and the value is the choosen option value. You defined the id to search for here: "<select id="quantity" "

Comment: i want to get the id value that is $qty->discount in id have a look at option tag <option value="<?=$i?>" id="<?=$qty->discount?>"><?=$i?></option> i am already getting option value by post method

Comment: And as far as i know, all that is send to the server is the value. So you will not be able to get the id, just the value. But you should be able to recalculate the quantity discount, if you got the right id, because they depend on each other if I understand your code right.

Comment: @ksome, do u have other method to recommend me i will try to change my code

Comment: You could try to do the following: change id `to:value="<?=$i?>_<?=$qty->discount?>"`. Important is, that this char :"_" is not in the other two variables. And then you could use split [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) or expplode [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to seperate the two values again: `explode  ( "_" , $this->input->get_post('quantity'))`

Comment: Wrote this solution with a little more detail in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, maybe it will work, Inside the `calculate(this)` function:

```
var discount = $("select[name='quantity'] option:selected").attr('id');
alert( discount );
$("#discount").val( discount ); //this will save the discount value in the hidden field
```

**EDIT**:

Put a hidden field in your form to contain the discount value

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount" id="discount">
```

Now, submit the form as usual. Hope it helps.

Comment: this is my question how to pass js discount variable to controller, when i submit the form then this variable should be submit

Answer (score 0):

**Use ajax call on change event of the selection of the options:**

Just Changed your code little :

```
<select id="quantity" name="quantity" tabindex="2" onchange="calculate(this)" required autofocus>
            <option value="0">Choose Your Quantity</option>
            <?php
                if( !empty($prodqty)):
                 foreach($prodqty as $qty):
                        for($i = $qty->quantity_from; $i <= $qty->quantity_to; $i++): ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $i?>" id="<?php echo $qty->discount?>"><?php echo $i?></option>
                        <?php endfor;
                    endforeach;
                  endif; ?>
        </select>
```

Your javascript function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function calculate(id)
{
    var id=id;
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'your controller/add_cart_prod',
            data:{'id':id},
            success:function(data){
                // the next thing you want to do 
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

Your Controller Function:

```
function add_cart_prod()
{
 $id=$this->input->post('id',true);

 //send this value to your model 
}
```